# Kubernetes remote cluster setup

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes

How I can setup and securely access a kubernetes cluster on EC2 instance from my laptop? I want it to be a single-node cluster, like running only one instance. Have tried run minikube at EC2 instance, but can't config laptop to connect to it.
So, in the result, I want to run like 10 services/pods in EC2 instance and just debug run on my dev laptop.

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kops checkout this tool for creating a cluster and follow the instructions for AWS https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/aws.md

Comment: @iamcaleberic yea, but this requires SecretAccessKey and AccessKeyID and will actually create instances per service/pods. But I need it to run on single server

Comment: It creates on flags passed to it in your case one `node` and one `master `and all the pods and services would be created on that node

Comment: it wont create instances per service or pod

Comment: I have a project called "aws-minikube" ... it uses Terraform to create the AWS resources and kubeadm to deploy Kubernetes ... check it out: https://github.com/scholzj/aws-minikube

I'm not sure what and how you want to debug, but it might help - you can use it in the same way as any big Kubernetes cluster with loadbalancers etc..

Comment: @iamcaleberic thanks! But how I can debug locally using telepresence.io? because I will need somehow connect to this cluster and provide some credentials or crt/key files? I'm new to kubernetes and I really appreciate your help

Comment: You can install the https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard and use `kubectl proxy` to proxy to your local machine and use the dashboard locally to add your services and pods/deployments...or you'll need to pass the `ssh key` which you can use to `ssh` to the `master node` and interact with the `cluster` from within master

Comment: @Jakub thanks, looks good, I will try too. But why it needs "ssh_public_key"? Thanks!

Comment: The ssh_public_key is installed on the EC2 host. It means that if you need you can log in using SSH directly into the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [KOPS (Kubernetes Ops)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) to Accomplish this. Its a really handy tool. There's a whole section for configuring a cluster on [AWS](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/aws.md). I use it on a couple of projects and id really recommend it. Its an easy to understand setup and straight forward.

After the cluster is up you can use `kubectl proxy` to proxy locally and interact with the cluster. Or use `kubectl` with config files to set up services and pods.

**It does not create a new instance per service or pod it creates a pod on the node(s) that is already existing on the cluster.**

In your case you could have a `single master` and a `single node` in whatever size that suits your needs.`t.2 micro` or otherwise

A command to accomplish that would look like:

```
 kops create cluster \
  --cloud aws \
  --state $KOPS_STATE_STORE \
  --node-count $NODE_COUNT \
  --zones $ZONES \
  --master-zones $MASTER_ZONES \
  --node-size $NODE_SIZE \
  --master-size $MASTER_SIZE \
  -v $V_LOG_LEVEL \
  --ssh-public-key $SSH_KEY_PATH \      
  --name=$CLUSTER_NAME
```

Where the `$NODE_COUNT` would be `1` thus having a single `Node or EC2 Instance` and another instance as the `master`

To connect to it locally you can also deploy the [kubernetes dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard) on your cluster.

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

To access Dashboard from your local workstation you must create a secure channel to your Kubernetes cluster. Run the following command:

```
 kubectl proxy
```

Now you can access the Dashboard at:

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

Comment: nice. But "to proxy locally and interact with the cluster." I actually need to debug on my laptop but it must be secured. Mean the only user with token/cert can add services. Can it be proxied with telepresence.io?

Comment: @TomWhite I havent used telepresence before but `kubectl` creates a secure channel which in turn runs on your `localhost:8001` at the above url

Comment: ok, but this is localhost on an EC2 instance. how can I add a service that is a docker container on my local workstation/laptop? I have tried that before and was not able to do curl /api by internal or public ip

Comment: This is not on the EC2 instance this is on your local machine it will proxy the cluster onto your local machine and run the dashboaed on your dev machine you'll be able to access it on  your `localhost:8001`. Its like you are opening a line to your cluster but accessing it on localhost.

Comment: so, I need to run "kubectl proxy" on my local machine, but then I need to specify an ip/port of cluster (EC2) instance, no?

Comment: I'm getting error if do `curl 127.0.0.1:8001/api` in my local macheine " http: proxy error: x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, MY_Internal_IP, not My_public_IP"

Comment: Ok did you follow the steps to create the cluster..on aws

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165684/discussion-between-iamcaleberic-and-tom-white).